# Add "New" Button to Metadata Related list

Tags: metadata, list-button, relatedlistnew

We have some related MetaData objects in Salesforce. However, when I'm on the parent metadata record, I can't add a child record from the related metadata record.

I'm thinking the only way I can do this is through a visual force page for the record, but is there a "clicks" rather than "code" option?

d[image]

Comment: Have you checked Buttons of the Related Lists on the Page Layout of the parent Object? Also, do you have Create permission for child Objects?

Comment: Are these plain objects or custom metadata?

Comment: These are Custom Metadata @rahulgawale. I have full admin rights, unless there is a special permission related to meta data. I checked the related lists on the page page layout of the parent object. Couldn't find anything about adding buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this much needed button is currently not available. For now you have to create child CMTs from their corresponding pages. e.g. go to Custom Metadata Types, "Manage Records" for the Child CMT, click "New", then manually fill in the parent lookup.

The alternative is to custom build your own UI. You will have to rely on the [Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata.htm#apex_metadata) namespace and deploy CMT records.

Btw [here is the Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000le18QAA) that you can upvote.